# Is it explained how Emile hides their anatomy?

Tags: hundred

Emile Crossford begins the series as Hayato's roomate.

[image: "Emile" Crossford]

But actually

> "He" is a girl disguised as boy.

But when he wears "other" clothes, it is shown that this disguise would be hard to mantain.

Does the franchise make any effort to explain how it is achieved? Or is it just handwaved?